# RedirectMatch on a cgi query not working

Tags: apache, mod-alias

I'm trying to redirect URLs to a cgi script that match certain criteria. I.e. I don't want to redirect every query to that script, just those with a particular parameter. But I can't get it to work. Here's my Redirect:

```
RedirectMatch /cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?BBID=(.*) http://adelaide.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com:1701/primo_library/libweb/action/dlDisplay.do?vid=SUA\&docId=SUA$1
```

I've used RedirectMatch successfully many, many times, but never before with a cgi script.
Anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

`mod_alias` only deals with the path part of the URL, not the query.

The directive below will redirect `http://example.com/old.html?name=value` to `http://example.com/new.html?name=value`. The `$` marks the end of the path, not the end of the URL.

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/old\.html$ /new.html
```

`mod_rewrite` is necessary to deal with (that is, rewrite) queries.